# How do I add custom HTML to Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a simple image gallery, where users can click on thumbnail images and Fancybox will open up the full-size image. Great, it works. Now, I want to add some custom HTML so the image is contained in a wrapper that has the title at the bottom, and photo comments to the right of the photo (think facebook). How do I do this? I've been trying for hours now to figure out how to do this, and all I can do is get the original photo to open up with Fancybox. Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
        padding     : 0,
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        closeBtn    : false,
        helpers : { 
            title       : { type : 'inside' },
            buttons     : {}
        }
    });
});
```

I'm looking for something like this (note the last line):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
        padding     : 0,
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        closeBtn    : false,
        helpers : { 
            title       : { type : 'inside' },
            buttons     : {},
            html : {'<div>my custom html</div>'}
        }
    });
});
```

How would I do this?

Comment: see [this](http://fancybox.net/blog) page on fancybox site. There you'll find examples of what you need.

Comment: @madfriend : wrong link, he is using version 2 (I guess you know there are two different sites for v1.x and v2.x, don't you?)

Comment: ooops, [link](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

Answer (score 14):

To popup custom HTML on Fancybox 2:

```
$.fancybox({ content: '<div>my custom html</div>' });
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4HBrQ/1/)

are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to understand what you did. I think I've got it?

Comment: Just hide the div which you want to show in fancy box. use the href of the anchor tag equal to the div and onclick call the fancy box function on the anchor tag. thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Did you say "*think facebook*" ? then you could also consider my fancybox "a la" Facebook :

http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html

It requires fancybox v2.x