# fancybox popup content including a twitter feed

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need to add a twitter feed to a fancybox pop up. Can it be done?

Here is a link to the current test implementation: [fancybox_test2](https://inetwebdesign.com/fancybox/fancybox_test2.html)

I need to add the twitter feed to the pop up as shown in this image: [image: screenshot]

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11356501/1055987